# NSFetchedResultsController given section name find the index of that section

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a NSFetchedResultsController with multiple sections. my app guarantee that the section name is unique. Now given a NSString I want to know if it is the name of any section. And if so, return me the section number of the matching section.

The naive way is to iterate self.fetchedResultsController.sections and compare the section name with the given string.

I am wondering if sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex can solve this issue better. 
the following code crashes:

```
  int temp = [self.fetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:@"A-Section-Name" atIndex:0];
```

What's is the proper way to find the section number of the section whose name matches the input string?

Thanks!

Erben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you've used is for section *index* titles (those displayed down the right of the whole table), not for section titles. You'll have to use the sections property, or cache the section titles yourself, but this probably isn't worth the effort. I'd do something like:

```
NSUInteger sectionIndex = [[self.fetchedResultsController.sections valueForKey:@"name"] indexOfObject:sectionName];
```

Where `sectionName` is the passed in name. This will set `sectionIndex` to the appropriate index, or `NSNotFound` if the section doesn't exist.

Calling `valueForKey:` on an array returns an array containing the values from that key on each item in an array. It's often overlooked and very useful.

This seems more immediately simple than any caching solution, since you don't need to keep a cache up to date. If you're not calling it tons of times in a loop, it should be fine.